# What is a regular expression in Python that would detect phone numbers of the format +1 ***-***-**98 in a string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I currently have a string where inside there are phone numbers with asterisked numbers of the format:

```
+1 ***-***-**98
```

The format is that there is a +1 at the beginning and two digits appear at the end. I am wondering if there might be a way to regex these using the `re` package. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/NFbzYW/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
\+1 (?:\*{3}-){2}\*{2}\d{2}
```

- `\+1` Matches substring `+1`.
- `(?:\*{3}-){2}` Non capturing group. Matches three `*` followed by two `-`. Group is repeated two times.
- `\*{2}` Matches two `*`.
- `\d{2}` Matches two digits.

Regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/rW3ukk/1).

---

In Python:

```
import re

phoneno = 'my number is +1 ***-***-**98'
match = re.search(r'\+1 (?:\*{3}-){2}\*{2}\d{2}',phoneno)
print(match.group(0))
```

Prints:

```
+1 ***-***-**98
```

Comment: The only possible issue in your answer is that some phone numbers may have more, or less, than three hyphen separated groups of numbers.  For example, here in Singapore, a number looks like `+65 1234-5678`, i.e. only 2 groups.  Your pattern would fail to catch this.

Comment: Actually, if the `+1` means US number, then your answer is fine, but it can't be generalized to other countries.

Comment: *The format is that there is a +1 at the beginning*

Comment: Right...so as long as this is for a US only phone number, then you're in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `re.match` here:

```
phone = "+1 ***-***-**98"
matches = re.match( r'\+1 \*+(?:-\*+)*\d{2}', phone)

if matches:
    print("match")
```

### Demo

- `\+1`       matches plus one
- `\*+`      match any number of *
- `(?:-\*+)*` then match -*+, any number of times
- `\d{2}`     match final two actual digits

Comment: Your regex matches `+1 *-*-*98` and `+1 *98`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness And...?  Why shouldn't it?  How do you know that every number would fit that format?

Comment: The pattern is pretty clear to me from the OP. Have you ever seen a number with four digits such as `+1 *98` ?

Comment: No, I haven't seen such a number.  But there may other number patterns which don't fit the answer you hard coded.  Just trying to be flexible.